# if unchecked script still working :( with ui.boxer whats wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hello I have a problem with this http://jsfiddle.net/E7dGA/1/
When the script starts and you don't check the checkbox everything is ok - the drawing doesn't occur. Next, when you check the box, still everything is ok (you can draw divs), but when you uncheck the checkbox, the you can still draw divs even if the checkbox is unchecked???

Whats wrong?

Comment: you should remove event of drawing beacause you set it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:
http://jsfiddle.net/E7dGA/2/
Change event for checkbox attach one time on init ui.boxer

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the functions (listeners) to handle the drawing when the checkbox is checked. Those functions don't disappear - they are still listening and doing the drawing, regardless of whether you check the box again or not.

Comment: You therefore need to check within the listeners whether the box is checked.

Comment: So how it will be in the code? Can you help Me?

Comment: Your question was "what's wrong" - I gave you the answer. ridecar2 added how to fix it - test the checkbox inside the listeners, e.g. `_mouseStart: function(event) { if (!div_action_check) return; etc...`

Comment: Still don't work. The same effect